# SQL Query to find used time slots for appointment not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL Query that looks for any time slots in the table.

My table has the following appointments slots reserved for a specific day - say 01/11/2020.

```
StartTime   EndTime
    09:55   10:55
    15:00   16:00
    14:00   15:00
    13:00   13:30
    12:15   16:00
    12:00   16:00
```

My SQL Query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        dbo.Appointment
    WHERE
                AppointmentDate = '01/11/2020'
                AND IsActive = 'True'
                AND
                (CAST(StartTime AS TIME) BETWEEN
                CAST('10:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('11:55' AS TIME)
                AND CAST(EndTime AS TIME) BETWEEN
                CAST('10:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('11:55' AS TIME))
```

The problem is that the query is returning zero rows. Infact, it should return me the row `09:55 and 10:55` as this record falls in the time range that I have provided: `10:00 - 11:55`

Can anyone help me to figure out the issue please?

Comment: Are you trying to find any slots which have any overlap?

Comment: @Schwern: Yes. And return me those records.

Comment: Edit to show the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slot does *not* overlap with another if it ends before the other starts, or it starts after the other ends.

```
where '11:55' < StartTime or EndTime < '10:00'
```

To find overlapping slots, [invert the rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). It ends after the other starts *and* it starts before the other ends.

```
where StartTime < '11:55' and '10:00' < EndTime
```

There's no need to cast the values, MySQL will do it for you, assuming StartTime and EndTime are `time` columns.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cdc9875c58eb941a1e1f57e84c8bd36).

Comment: This is why I use Event A and Event B for this description (even though the events are interchangeable)

Comment: @Strawberry Hmm, [pronoun trouble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vbw5DmVENlU#t=1m40s).

Comment: I note that your choice of db doesn't match the tags. Nevertheless, I suspect it's the correct one!

Comment: FWIW, I think the tags are wrong, not you!